# How to avoid fragment overlay while doing a replace FragmentTransaction with a customAnimation

Tags: android, android-fragments

Using the following code, I'm replacing a fragment by another:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if(anomalieFragment == null)
{
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_out_right, R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right, R.animator.slide_in_left);
    anomalieFragment = new AnomalieListFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.content, anomalieFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
}
```

Where `slide_in_left` and `slide_out_right` is defined like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="500"
            android:propertyName="XFraction"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="100"
            android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="500"
            android:propertyName="XFraction"
            android:valueFrom="100"
            android:valueTo="0"
            android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Once the transistion is completed, everything is fine, there is no overlay, but when the transition is in action, the old fragment is still visible under the new fragment.

Transition in progress - 1
[image: Transition in progress - 1] 
Transition in progress - 2
[image: Transition in progress - 2]

Is there something I can do to avoid that?

**EDIT**

Here's the implementation of XFraction (I created a FrameLayout derived class:

SlidingFrameLayout

```
package com.aquadata.tutorials.FirstApp.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import com.aquadata.fms.R;
import com.google.android.gms.internal.x;

/**
 * Created by igirouard on 2014-08-27.
 * FrameLayout supportant d'être slidé in an out par le R.animator.slide_in_left et slide_out_right
 * Supporte aussi que son enfant contienne une vue id/shadow pour afficher un ombrage quand
 */
public class SlidingFrameLayout extends FrameLayout
{
    //Position initiale du layout, telle que définie dans OnLayout
    float initialX = -1;

    //Dernière fraction
    float _xFraction = -1;

    public SlidingFrameLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SlidingFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SlidingFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    //Retourne la fraction de la position initiale par rapport à la position lors du slide
    private float getXFraction()
    {
        return getWidth() == 0 ? 0 :(getX() - initialX) / getWidth() * 100;
    }

    //Déterminer un nouveau x selon la fraction de déplacement domandée
    public void setXFraction(float xFraction)
    {
        _xFraction = xFraction;
        if(initialX != -1.0f && getWidth() != 0)
        {
            final float newX = initialX + (xFraction / 100 * getWidth());
            setX(newX);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called from layout when this view should
     * assign a size and position to each of its children.
     *
     * Derived classes with children should override
     * this method and call layout on each of
     * their children.
     * @param changed This is a new size or position for this view
     * @param left Left position, relative to parent
     * @param top Top position, relative to parent
     * @param right Right position, relative to parent
     * @param bottom Bottom position, relative to parent
     *
     * Si une ombre a été ajoutée au layout, la cacher si on est à x == 0
     */
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        if(changed)
            initialX = left;


        super.onLayout(changed, left,top,right,bottom);

        if(_xFraction != -1)
            setXFraction(_xFraction);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to set not transparent background to second fragment

Comment: @Eldar The background is already opaque

Comment: Checked same animations with simple fragments and haven't observed the issue. There's smth wrong with fragments background or/and you implementation of xFraction property. Please, share complete example.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this similar issue by setting the background color:

```
android:background="@color/background_material_light"
```